# setState does not update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

why this.setState does not work.

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state ={
    obj: [],
 }
 }
 ,


componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
const { obj } = this.props;
  this.setState({obj});
}
}
```

Comment: try console logging `this.props.siteDataState`

Comment: Never use `setState` unconditionally in `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: There is no prop `siteDataState`

Answer (score 4):

If you look at your dev console you'll see an error when that console log is supposed to occur, because you're using a "normal" function without any kind of `this` preservation. Instead, once that function gets called the `this` identifier will be referencing the global context (e.g. `window`), rather than your component.

Use an arrow function to make sure `this` is the one you *actually* meant, and you'll see that `setState` worked just fine:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  this.setState({
    siteDataState: this.props.siteData
  }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.siteDataState);
  });
}
```

That said, this is going to cascade-trigger because you're changing the component *in the function that triggers when the component changes*, so put some `if` code in there that makes sure that `this.state.siteDataState` isn't *already* what's in `this.props.siteData`.

Comment: sure,, but this is not work for me, can you test without callback , i use call back just for debug data, i need to update stat

Comment: So do some basic debugging: prove to yourself that `this.props` has content that you can actually extract by just having `componentDidUpdate` be a single line of code: `console.log(this.props)`. Does it even have the value you're trying to rebind to state? (also, if you're already getting this passed down as prop, why are you adding it into state at all? Just reference `this.props.siteData` instead of `this.state.siteDataState`. There is no good reason to rebind it)